# Validate Value Between 1-24 In Parking Calculator

Tags: c#

So i have an assignment where i need to validate that a number entered from the keyboard is between 1-24. The code for the calculator is below and is simple. It takes the value entered and multiplies it by 2.5 to a max of 20. I need to add code to make sure the number entered is between 1-24. Please Help. I think i need another if/else statement.

/* Harrison Currie
             * 24/03
             * Assignment Parking Fee 1
             * Pseudocode
             * HOURLY RATE = 2.50
             * PARKING FEE = HOURS *Fee
             * MAX FEE = 20.00
             * OUTPUT TOTAL COST TO A MAX OF $20
             * Validate Hours are between 1-24
             */

```
        //Set Constants
        const decimal HOURLY_RATE = 2.5m;
        const decimal MAX_FEE = 20.00m;
        //Declare Variables
        decimal PARKING_FEE;
        decimal HOURS;
        //Input
        //Enter HOURS as a decimal

        PARKING_FEE = HOURS * HOURLY_RATE;


        bool valid = false;
        while (!valid)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Enter Number Of Hours Parked");
            HOURS = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            if (HOURS > 0 && HOURS <= 24)
            {
                valid = true;
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Hours must be between 1-24");
            }

            if (PARKING_FEE >= 20.00m)
            {
                PARKING_FEE = MAX_FEE;
            }
            else
            {
                PARKING_FEE = HOURS * HOURLY_RATE;
            }
            //Output
            Console.WriteLine("Developed By Harrison Currie");
            Console.WriteLine("The Cost Of Your Park Is $" + PARKING_FEE);
            Console.Read();
```

Comment: What exactly is your problem? The textual description is almost already C# code: If the entered value is greater than 24, then print an error message and exit the program.

Comment: You've already got code that checks `PARKING_FEE` so you appear to know how do use an `if` statement. You could use that to just quit (return) if `HOURS` is lower than 1 or more than 24. Now would also be a good time to learn C# naming conventions - normal local variables would be written like `parkingFee` and `hours`, and constants would be `HourlyRate` and `MaxFee`. I'd also encourage you to only declare variables at the point of first use, rather than declaring them all before you start any of the rest of the code.

Comment: Hi daisy. Thanks for your quick response. How would i go about coding in the part where if hours is lower than 1 or more than 24 a message saying "invalid" shows and the coding pauses to display that and not the further write lines.

Comment: When you say "the coding pauses" - do you mean you want the user to enter a new value, or are you happy to say "Invalid" and then make the program finish? For the first option, you'll need to use a *loop* - have you learned about those yet?

Comment: Yeah i just need too make it so if the number entered is not between 1 and 24 "invalid" displays and sits there. If the value is between 1-24 then the fee is calculated and the code displays the other message showing the total.

Comment: something like do { ... } while ( HOURS < 1 || HOURS > 24 ); around the input code

Comment: "and sits there" - forever? Without either the program completing or asking the user to enter a new value?

Answer (score 0):

Add while, and check, if entered is in range. And some info message for it.
something like that:

```
   /* Harrison Currie
                * 24/03
                * Assignment Parking Fee 1
                * Pseudocode
                * HOURLY RATE = 2.50
                * PARKING FEE = HOURS *Fee
                * MAX FEE = 20.00
                * OUTPUT TOTAL COST TO A MAX OF $20
                * Validate Hours are between 1-24
                */

        //Set Constants
        const decimal HOURLY_RATE = 2.5m;
        const decimal MAX_FEE = 20.00m;
        //Declare Variables
        decimal PARKING_FEE;
        decimal HOURS =0;
        //Input
        bool valid = false;

        while (!valid)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Enter hours of parking: ");
         bool parse =  decimal.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(),out HOURS);
            if (!parse)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Not a number.");
                continue;
            }

            if(HOURS > 0 && HOURS <= 24)
            {
                valid = true;
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Hours must be between 0-24");
            }
        }
        PARKING_FEE = HOURS * HOURLY_RATE;


        if (PARKING_FEE >= 20.00m) PARKING_FEE = MAX_FEE;
        else PARKING_FEE = HOURS * HOURLY_RATE;
        //Output
        Console.WriteLine("Developed By Harrison Currie");
        Console.WriteLine("The Cost Of Your Park Is $" + PARKING_FEE);
        Console.Read();
```

Comment: the code looks like this but now has a "Use of unassigned local variable "HOURS" error. ill change the above code so it fits. refer to original please.

Comment: assign 0 to it at beginning

Comment: decimal HOURS = 0;

Comment: Thanks Raichiks. I've made that change and it displays the correct text when its not between 1-24 but it no longer keeps it to a max of 20. i can enter 23 hours and it does not default back to the MAX_FEE of $20. It also shows the bottom write lines regardless of the hours being between 1-24. How do i stop the code if its not between 1-24 and thus not show the other writelines below.

Comment: add while before check and do next your steps afterwards

Comment: @Harry: It sounds like you've replaced the wrong piece of code. I would take a step back at this stage - do you understand how the code in this answer works? Do you understand how your existing code works? If so, you should be able to piece them together. If not, I suspect you're best off asking your teacher for some more help. Stack Overflow is great for specific problems, but it doesn't work well in a tutorial sort of sense.

Comment: @DaisyShipton comment in place, my code had to be putted //Input
        Console.WriteLine("Enter Number Of Hours Parked");
        HOURS = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine()); //Enter HOURS as a decimal
        //Processing    only in place of code after first comment

Comment: @raichiks: Yup, *I* understand the code that had to be replaced, but I'm concerned that if Harry was having problems, he may not fully understand the code, which means it's not terribly useful for an assignment.

Comment: Thankyou for your help and concern daisy. My lecturer is not able to help me with this and i have actually done a more advanced code but forgot to submit this one so i had to go back. With the code as it is right now shown above how do i get the code to pause if the hours are not between 1-24. The max fee also no longer works with the current code.

Comment: take your previous code from your post edit history in stackowerflow and than replace correct lines of code from my answer

Comment: I've added in a readkey and that stops the code if the hours are not between 1-24. Now the issue is the max fee doesn't work if the hours are valid.

Comment: Something was not correct I guess, I updated my answer, try that

Comment: Ok it works perfectly now thank you so much!! and thank you daisy, You have helped me out quite a lot. <3